# Static IP for internal communication in AWS for microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 7 Spring microservices with Eureka Server which I would like to deploy into AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Every time when I redeploy microservice I see that the url address is changed. Is it possible to use internal static IP for every AWS service?

Comment: Private ip addresses do not change. So I'm not sure what do you mean?

Comment: Private IP are assigned to each AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance? Where I can see that?

Comment: In EC2 console. Go to your eb instance in the EC2 console, and it will be there in `Networking` under `Private IPv4 addresses`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this problem with managing EB instances remotely, I have fixed this in two ways:

1. For myself I use `eb ssh` from EB CLI to remotely access instances. As the CLI gives you an option to select which instance you want to connect to if there are more than one. If your microservices are in a private subnet you need a [bastion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-bastion-host.html) to connect to your instances remotely.
2. using AWS System manager / Session Manager
   You can install a System manager agent on your elastic beanstalk environment using ebextensions. Using Systems managers; Session manager you can start a session towards your microservice and all your commands will be logged towards S3 (can be usefull for change management / complaincy)

As I want straight to these two options; I never fixed the issue where private IP's changed.